# java.lang.Exception: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception

Tags: validation, websphere

We are getting the below mentioned error on websphere 8.5

2020-01-07 15:19:37 [] DEBUG InvocableHandlerMethod.java.getMethodArgumentValues:174: 
Could not resolve parameter [1] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity 
com.mycorp.uap.controller.WorkFlowController.updateTask(int,com.mycorp.uap.rest.vo.TaskVO) 
throws java.lang.Exception: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.

Method is defined as

```
public ResponseEntity<TaskVO> updateTask(@PathVariable("id") int taskId, @Valid @RequestBody(required=true) TaskVO task) throws Exception{
```

WEB-INF/lib contains the below jars related to hibernate, validation and spring

hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar

hibernate-core-5.4.4.Final.jar

hibernate-ehcache-5.4.4.Final.jar

hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.jar

hibernate-validator-6.0.15.Final.jar

validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar

spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-support-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

springfox-core-2.1.2.jar

springfox-schema-2.1.2.jar

springfox-spi-2.1.2.jar

springfox-spring-web-2.1.2.jar

springfox-swagger2-2.1.2.jar

springfox-swagger-common-2.1.2.jar

springfox-swagger-ui-2.1.2.jar

spring-hateoas-0.17.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar

spring-messaging-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-acl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-cas-client.jar

spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-ldap-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-oauth2-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-openid-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-taglibs-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-test-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar

ParentLast setting is present in WebSphere configuration for our application so that WebSphere should give preference to the jars present in the WEB-INF/lib of our application

There is a similar method where @Valid is not present which works properly.

I looked into similar question on the stack overflow however could not quite get the correct solution.

What should be the correct solution?
Should we remove any jars from our WEB-INF/lib?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you need to add the HibernatePersistenceProviderResolver class to your project:

[HibernatePersistenceProviderResolver.java](https://pastebin.com/vVQCVrX2)

and register it in the Application class in the onStartup method

```
@Override 
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    HibernatePersistenceProviderResolver.register();
    ... 
}
```

[Reference](https://giancarloparma.com/tag/developer/)